# How to specify multiple possibilities for rust trait bounds

Tags: rust, traits, trait-bounds

I am trying to write a function that takes any iterable to a generic type as input and loops over the elements. Here is a working example

```
 pub fn test1<'a, IterableT, ItemT>(nodes: &'a IterableT)
    where 
        &'a IterableT: IntoIterator<Item = &'a ItemT>,
        ItemT: 'a + Debug
    {
        for x in nodes {
            println!("consuming or iterating: {:?}!", x);
        }
    }
```

This works with reference types. I struggle to implement a version that works with both regular types and references. The closest I have got it the following

```
 pub fn test1<IterableT>(nodes: IterableT)
    where 
        IterableT: IntoIterator,
        IterableT::Item: Debug
    {
        for x in nodes {
            println!("consuming or iterating: {:?}!", x);
        }
    }
```

This works as long as the reference version of the type I am using implements IntoIterator (for example `vec`, `&vec` and `&mut vec`). The problem is that I can't reintroduce the `ItemT` generic since then the underlying `Item` is narrowed down to one of `Item` or `&Item`

```
 pub fn test1<IterableT, ItemT>(nodes: IterableT)
    where 
        IterableT: IntoIterator<Item = ItemT>, // alternatively IntoIterator<Item = &ItemT>
        ItemT: Debug
    {
        for x in nodes {
            println!("consuming or iterating: {:?}!", x);
        }
    }
```

Depending on whether I use `IntoIterator<Item = ItemT>` or `IntoIterator<Item = &ItemT>`, this works with `vec` or `&vec` but not both. A hacky workaround is to specify `IterableT::Item: Into<ItemT>`, but this only works if the underlying type implements the Into traits (so this will work with built-in types like i32, i64, but not for some custom made struct).

Is there a way to indicate that `Item` can either be `ItemT` or `&ItemT` in the `where` clause? The reason I need to introduce `ItemT` is because it is a generic variable of the parent struct that this function is a part of. I need to accept iterators specifically with that type.

Comment: Why not? If you use `Item = ItemT` it works great with both: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bab077fd8b51ba1430206f0d95f885f5.

Comment: It doesn't work if I use  `test1::<_, i32>(&data)` instead of just `test1(&data)`. Basically in my example `ItemT` comes from the parent struct, so I can't let the compiler infer it. My code looks something like this: `impl<ItemT> MyStruct<ItemT> { fn test1<Iterable>(nodes: Iterable) ... }`. Sorry, I probably should have included the full context in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::borrow::Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) to treat `T` and `&T` the same.

```rust
use std::{borrow::Borrow, fmt::Debug};

fn debug_iterator<I, T>(it: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Borrow<T>,
    T: Debug + ?Sized,
{
    for item in it.into_iter() {
        println!("  item: {:?}", item.borrow());
    }
}
```

In action:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![String::from("hello"), String::from("world")];

    println!("By reference:");
    debug_iterator::<_, String>(v1.iter());
    
    println!("By value:");
    debug_iterator::<_, String>(v1);
}
```

Output:

```
By reference:
  item: "hello"
  item: "world"
By value:
  item: "hello"
  item: "world"
```

Note that because the `Borrow` trait has a type parameter, you have to provide the correct type for `T` explicitly at the call site; Rust will not be able to infer the type you want.

Comment: Nice! I see in the standard library that borrow<T> is implemented for &T (for arbitrary generic T). Didn’t realize implementing traits for arbitrary types like that was possible.